# Android WebView makes the device unstable

Tags: java, android, security, web

I am displaying a WebView in android its basically a simple web browser, when i use it the operating system becomes unstable i think it is because the browser does not have some kind of web security measures so i think the problem is caused by a virus that infects the device when the user access websites from this app.

The implementation of WebView is as follows:

```
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {}});
    webview.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

How can i solve this problem, and how hard is it to solve?